# Azure Files ContentSettings data_type

Tags: python, azure

I am setting up a python script to upload files to an Azure FileShare. I am following [this official tutorial for SDK v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=python2).

Now, the tutorial uses this argument: `content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/png')`. My point is that the class `ContentSettings` is not very well documented and I have no idea what values of `content_type` are valid. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.models.contentsettings?view=azure-python-previous) is the official documentation I could find. Does anyone know where I can find a list of valid content types for this argument? What happens if this argument is mis-specified?

Comment: See if this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for your comment! Do you think that that list is applicable to the argument? I am wondering if there is any official guidance or we should simply assume. Thanks again

Comment: AFAIK, there are no rules for the content type.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if this argument is mis-specified?

Adding to what @GauravMantri have mentioned, when you are trying to set the content type of the file other than the actual content type, the file will be no longer be in a valid format except for few of the content types and cannot be read.

For demonstration purposes, I have used the same sample as mentioned in the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=python2#upload-a-file). Below is the code I'm using.

> ````
> azure.storage.file import FileService
>
> file_service = FileService(account_name='<ACCOUNT_NAME>',
> account_key='<ACCOUNT_KEY>')
>
> file_service.create_file_from_path(
>     '<FILESHARE_NAME>',
>     None,
>     'sunset.png',
>     'sunset.png',
>     content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='video/x-msvideo')) ```
> ````

### Results

Below are the results that I got when I'm trying to download a `image/png` file as `video/x-msvideo` content type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you expand on the following points:

1. "the file will be no longer be in a valid format except for few of the content types and cannot be read"? What would these formats be? 

2. The download fail you show...is it something you would get even from Python? For example using the get_file_to_path method shown in the (usual) official documentation?

Thanks again